# Generate valid ical file on linux

Tags: linux, shell, icalendar, kde-plasma

Is there a simple way to create a valid icalendar file for a single appointment providing date, time, title and description on the linux commandline? Note that this data might have to be escaped properly.
I looked at konsolecalendar (kde) but it seems to be broken on my kubuntu linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Python library that could be used to create a simple command-line utility for this purpose:

https://icalendar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

There is also Calcurse, a text-based calendar and scheduling application.

> -x[format], --export[=format] Export user data to specified format. Events, appointments and todos are converted and echoed to stdout. Two
>   possible formats are available: ical and pcal. If the optional
>   argument format is not given, ical format is selected by default.

http://culot.org/calcurse/